# Extracting variables from request body

Tags: apigee

I want to grab variables from within the JSON body of the request. Currently, I have this extract variables policy in my request pre-flow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ExtractVariables async="false" continueOnError="true" enabled="true" name="extractvariables-grabrequestpayload">
<DisplayName>ExtractVariables-GrabRequestPayload</DisplayName>
<Source clearPayload="false">request</Source>
<FaultRules/>
<Properties/>
<IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>true</IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>
<JSONPayload>
    <Variable name="payload">
        <JSONPath>$</JSONPath>
    </Variable>
    <Variable name="method">
        <JSONPath>$.method</JSONPath>
    </Variable>
</JSONPayload>
<VariablePrefix>myprefix</VariablePrefix>
```

A sample request body is as follows:

{
  "method": "CANCEL",
  "params": {
    "partition":"05",
    "itemnumber": "1",
    "recipientnumber": "1",
    "sku":"0JAX330000"
  }
}

However, I am not seeing the variables in trace, even though I can see that the content.request is correctly getting populated with the JSON above and the policy is being executed. I can't see any reference to grabbing this from the request body, only the response. Is this not possible?

Comment: I added a script and policy to examine the values. It appears that the original issue was that content type header wasn't being set as  "application/json". Now I see that the payload variable is being set, but not the method variable utilizing the payload included above.

Answer (score 1):

ExtractVariables policy will not display the variables through the UI. You can use a JavaScript policy to debug your code and display these variables. This policy should be executed after ExtractVariables policy. Then Trace Tool should display the variables.

```
context.getVariable('myprefix.payload');
context.getVariable('myprefix.method');
```

You can also set another variable to see the actual value:

```
context.setVariable('method-in-JavaScript', context.getVariable('myprefix.method') )
```

Answer (score 1):

Few things to try :

1. Content-Type must be `application/json` for apigee jsonpath extraction to work
2. download the debug-trace. In the XML file look for `<Point id="Execution">` and `<Property name="stepDefinition-name">extractvariables-grabrequestpayload</Property>`.  This is your extract variable policy execution step. Here inside this Point id check for VariableAccess element. If anything was set it would be shown here. Like `<Set name="extractvariables-1.invoked" success="true" value="true"/>`. This indicates that the policy was successfully executed and if any variables were set.
3. Also try to use $.'' for selecting the whole payload. (Two single quotes with empty content.)
4. To be sure that any variable was extracted you can use that variable in a policy after this. That should also print out the variable access in the debug log.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the classic(older) version of trace tool?
You might want to try click on "Try the new BETA version TRACE" on the right hand corner.
Let me know if using that shows up your variables you are looking for.

Comment: I have tried both--mostly the BETA. Either way, the variables are not even showing up.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of debugging variables inline is shown in the variables sample proxy:

https://github.com/apigee/api-platform-samples/tree/master/sample-proxies/variables

It can be useful to write variables into response HTTP headers so that you can immediately see the result of a new JSONPath, for example, as you iterate.